# spring framework / spring boot / module-info.java files

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud

if we want create binary (own jre) with use of jlink tool, jlink won't create binary if application has automatic modules.

is there any update on adding module-info.java files in spring framework / spring boot libraries ?

Comment: i've found this on spring framework bugzilla, it is related to my question,
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13501 when this is going to be fixed, can some contributor from spring framework answer this.. i'm asking here instead of question as github issue?

Comment: I've asked in this issue. Let's wait an answer.